# How to stop resizing of widgets when resizing browser page in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How do you stop the automatic resizing/responsiveness of widgets in Flutter Web.

Is there a way to use a Widget wrapped around the Scaffold, for example, that stops widgets from resizing when page window is resized?

I have a unique use case where responsiveness is not required (although I am aware that responsive design is best usually).

Answer (score 1):

You can give a fix `height` and `width` of that particular widget like this

```
SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: your_widget,
    );
```

And wrap parent widget with `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kIsWeb` this will identify if you are running on mobile or web app. You still have the same output for responsive layout on mobile and web but it will differ on running either web or mobile.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

kIsWeb ? WebWidget : MobileWidget
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but this is what worked for me:

```
return Center(
    child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
        width: 1000, //fixed width that you need
           child: <your widget that you don't want to resize>,
              ),
             ]
            ),
           )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).